# Can’t update table ‘xxx’ in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my system products table and stock table.

I have a trigger on delete in the stock table to update the product table like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Stock_Delete_Update_Products` AFTER DELETE ON  
`netshop_stock` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE products SET 
products_last_modified = NOW( ) WHERE products_model = old.product_model;
```

Now when I try to prrform this operation I get the error

```
delete from netshop_stock 
where netshop_stock.product_model in (select distinct 
products.products_model from products  where products.products_esd=1);
```

I understand that the select query locks the product table and thus is hindering the the trigger. Is there a way to prevent locking from the select statement ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory and says that a trigger cannot be used to modify a table which invoked that trigger.  One trick which might work would be to wrap the `products` table in a subquery.  MySQL materializes subqueries and this might get around the problem.

```
DELETE FROM netshop_stock 
WHERE netshop_stock.product_model IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT p.products_model
    FROM (SELECT * FROM products) p
    WHERE p.products_esd = 1
)
```